# Amazon EC2 instance was not available for few minutes (amazon showed that everything ok)

Tags: amazon-ec2, availability

Few minutes ago my amazon Ec2 instance was unavailable for a few minutes. During this time neither I was able to connect to web-site with http, nor I was able to ssh to it.

Also I was not able to connect to my amazon management console for some time (less than amount of unavailability of my instance). When I was able to connect to management console, it was showing me that everything is running smoothly (but I still was not able to connect to instance in any way for a minute or two). During this time I have checked their [status page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/) just to see that there is no issues (my instance is in Ireland and there is nothing wrong there today).

After that I was able to log in. I checked my logins with `last` to see that no one except me was logging in. I also looked in apache logs and there was no errors or warnings during this time.

Right now when I see my amazon monitor, I see a small spike in CPU in last 15 minutes (but this is from 10% to like 20%)

I have no idea what can it be (I have never experienced anything like this before) and therefore I have no idea how scared should I be or what else should I look for.

Can anyone give me a hint what my actions should be in such situation?